# alertmanger cannot load configuration file

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I am getting the following error message on starting Alertmanager:

```
/alertmanager/config.yml err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 48: cannot unmarshal !!map into []*config.WebhookConfig"
```

The only difference to a working config file is adding the following to the end of the file:

```
- name: 'zisalert'
    webhook_configs:
      send_resolved: true
      url: 'https://zisalert:9000/alert'
```

I am using Alertmanager 0.15.2.

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a yaml indentation problems. A functioning web hook receever block would look like this

```
- name: 'zisalert'
  webhook_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    url: 'https://zisalert:9000/alert'
```